# User not listed in /etc/passwd

Tags: users, top

As far as I thought, the list of users for my system can be printed in the terminal with:

```
sed 's/\([^:]*\).*/\1/' /etc/passwd
```

But I have noticed that when I use

```
top
```

In the USER column, my user name is listed for some running processes, but it is abbreviated to the first five letters with a "+" on the end, and there is a user that is not listed in the /etc/passwd file called "debian-+".

Why is this not listed and why is myusername abbreviated to "myuse+"?

Comment: `getent passwd | cut -d: -f1` will list all user accounts valid for your system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/etc/passwd` is one of many possible user databases. Others include things like IPA. You can use `getent` to see the *effective* `passwd` database.

As for the shortening of the user name, that's just the way `top` displays; sadly it looks like [that can't be changed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/104990/8965). You might want to try the `w` command.